# Android VideoView and ImageView rotate image

Tags: android, xml

Good night, I am making an android app and in some views I have `ImageViews` and `VideoViews`, but the problem is that when I am playing a video or displaying an image, it appears on the horizontal. Someone knows what is the reason ? 
Here is my XML code for one of the views:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scroll" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="460dp" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileImage"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fullName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nickName"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/profileImage"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nickName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profileImage"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileImage"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/saveImageNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/profileImage"
                android:layout_below="@+id/profileImage"
                android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
                android:background="@null" 
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/saveImageYes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/saveImageNo"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fullName"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" 
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout> 

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#DCDCDC"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="#808080"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean on the horizontal? How do you want your view display to be?

Comment: Instead of the image appears visually on vertical, I need to turn the phone to see it straight...

Comment: You want to force your Activity to show on Portrait Mode only. Is that it?

Comment: No, all of my activities are on portrait mode, just the videoviews and imageviews are displaying videos and images on horizontal... I don't know how to explain this better.

Comment: Is the content in it's raw form oriented correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand...

Comment: On your layout, what is wrong? What do you want to change? Is it your ImageView position?